# Knockout remove function on observable array not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, observable

In my knockout application I'm trying to remove an element using `remove` method.
But i'm getting the error

> **.remove is not a function**

Below is the code

```
ActivityArray = ko.observable([]);
ActivityArray(result.Regular); //Result of an api call    
ActivityArray.remove(function (element) { return element.Name === 'abc'; })
```

Not able to understand why it's not working. I have used `remove` in other places and every other place its working fine.

Please Guide

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.remove`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#replace-remove-and-removeall) function is available only for `observableArray`. But you are setting `ActivityArray` as an `observable`. Change it to an `observableArray`

```
ActivityArray = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an `observableArray` (https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html), not an `observable`.

```js
var viewmodel = function(){
  var self = this;
  var ActivityArray = ko.observableArray([]);
  var result = {
    "Regular":[
      {"Name": "abc"},
      {"Name": "xyz"}
    ]
  };
  ActivityArray(result.Regular); //Result of an api call
  console.log("Before remove: ", ActivityArray());
  ActivityArray.remove(function (element) { return element.Name === 'abc'; });
  console.log("After remove: ", ActivityArray());

};

ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```